# Clojure creating a flat map with for

Tags: clojure

I'm working my way through [4clojure](https://www.4clojure.com) and I'm stuck on [Problem 156](https://www.4clojure.com/problem/60) (Map Defaults).

I can't figure out why the function bellow doesn't return a flat map

```
((fn [d k] (for [i k :let [r {}]]
    (conj r [i d])))
    [:a :b] [:foo :bar])
```

Current result is `({:foo [:a :b]} {:bar [:a :b]})`

But I expected `{:foo [:a :b], :bar [:a :b]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `for`, `r` is created anew in every iteration, gets populated with `[i d]` and gets yielded as an element of the lazy sequence. As a result, you obtain this sequence whose elements are small one-entry maps.

What you need is `reduce`. It loops over a sequence updating the accumulator using a function you provide:

```
(defn fun1 [d k] 
  (reduce 
    (fn [acc i] (conj acc [i d])) 
    {} 
    k))
```

It starts from an empty map, and for every element `i` in `k` it calls the lambda, which adds an entry to the map (passed to the lambda as `acc`). The result is one big map with all these entries.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could just generate the key/value pairs with your `for` expression, and then use the [`into` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/into) to shove them all in a map:

```
((fn [d k] (into {} (for [i k] [i d])))
  [:a :b] [:foo :bar])
; => {:foo [:a :b], :bar [:a :b]}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here looking for a flatmap function in Clojure, check out [`mapcat`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapcat):

> Returns the result of applying concat to the result of applying map to
>   f and colls.